# 'Connection Interrupted' when running simple "Hello World" Python script on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, network-programming

I'm trying to write a simple script that sends a "Hello World" to the browser. While my current script works perfectly running on `localhost`, something goes wrong on Heroku and my script fails to send the response. I see 'Something went wrong' when accessing it on my browser.

Here is the current form of my script:

```
import socket
from random import choice
import os
if 'PORT' in os.environ:
    HOST, PORT = '', int(os.environ['PORT'])
else:
    HOST, PORT = '', choice(range(4000, 10000))
listen_socket = socket.socket()
listen_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
listen_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
listen_socket.listen(1)
print 'Serving HTTP on port %s ...' % PORT
while True:
    client_connection, client_address = listen_socket.accept()
    request = client_connection.recv(4096)
    print request

    http_response = """\
        HTTP/1.1 200 OK

        Hello, World!
                    """
    client_connection.sendall(http_response)
    client_connection.close()
```

From the logs, the relevant entries seem to be:

`2015-08-02T14:07:51.824720+00:00 heroku[router]: sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted" method=GET path="/" host=pastethatcode.herokuapp.com request_id=7b9dd237-349d-4f3b-89db-645960f6f2de fwd="182.66.57.92" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=1ms status=503 bytes=40`

Also, note that the `print request` line gets executed in my script(i. e. the logs have output from my app).

Comment: Well, it seems nobody knows :/